# How to handle merged cells when inserting data table with ClosedXML?

Tags: datatable, closedxml

I'm using ClosedXML it has a method called `InsertData` to insert a `DataTable` like this:

```
var rangeWithData = worksheet.Cell(row, cell).InsertData(dataTable.AsEnumerable());
```

as mentioned here: [ClosedXML Inserting data](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Inserting%20Data)

In my xml I have one merged column and it causes to miss one column from the data table.
Is there a way to handle it and still use the `InsertData` method or should I loop over the data table...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `InsertData` if you know beforehand which cells are merged and prepare the `DataTable` accordingly.

If you don't know that you have to use loops and move the data when you get to the merged cells.